# Mysql 'where' condition is not working for SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
$sql="select last_logged_out_at from `users`";
$sql.="WHERE xxxxxxx = '11112000'";
$rslt=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($rslt);
print_r($row);
```

Not working "where condition"; if I remove where then it takes data from table and if I change the condition to some other value in table, then it also works. Particular column "xxxxxxx" this query is not working please help me ..

Comment: 1) Have you tried executing the query itself in PHPmyAdmin or a similar tool? 2) Is there any data in your table, that should be returned (doublecheck this!)? 3) Add some error checking using `mysql_error()`. 4) You should switch to PDO or `mysqli` as `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Comment: please post the error here

Comment: Can you post the table description?

Comment: ya tried in phpmyamin but that works there

Comment: there is no error message shown

Comment: You are saying that 'Where' condition is not working and you are also saying that there is no error message. How this is possible? How do you know that its not working? btw, whats the datatype of the field 'XXXXXX'?

Answer (score 4):

You have no whitespace between the end of your first line and the start of the second:

`$sql.=" WHERE xxxxxxx = '11112000'";`

Comment: It would be a little bit clearly if you add second line to your code with 7 spaces and `^` symbol ))

Comment: the backtics also act as a separator so I guess that is not the issue

Comment: "if i change the condition to some other value in table then also working" - already mentioned in question. Please help me understand that if the space is problem then how it is working perfectly when some other value is used.

Comment: @Bhavik Shah dude do you have any solution for this...?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that's because there's no space between "users" and "WHERE".

Answer (score 1):

Because db column `"xxxxxxx"` (which you are using in `WHERE` clause) is a MySQL keyword. So, use:

```
WHERE `xxxxxxx` = '11112000'
```

instead of

```
WHERE xxxxxxx = '11112000'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write query in single sql.

```
$sql="select last_logged_out_at from users WHERE xxxxxxx = '11112000'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="select last_logged_out_at from `users` "; //enter a space after `users`
$sql.=" WHERE xxxxxxx = '11112000'"; // or enter a space before WHERE
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the column name in the database. Name include symbol like '_' so  it won't be conflict.